# How to paginate on the nested array in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

This is how my item schema looks in my dynamoDB table with table name "Topic".

```
{
        "topicId": "string",
        "topic": "string",
        "updatedTimeUTC": "number",
        "articles": [
            {
                "articleId": "string",
                "headline": "string",
                "updatedTimeUTC": "number"
            },
            {
                "articleId": "string",
                "headline": "string",
                "updatedTimeUTC": "number"
            }
        ],
        "articleCount": "number"
    }
```

As you can see each item represents a **topic** and each topic will have list of **articles** associated with it.

My access patterns looks like these:

1. Need to fetch topics with sorting order of **updatedTimeUTC** by pagination with page-size 5.
2. On fetch of single topic item using topicId, I should be able to paginate the articles array.

I can able to achieve the **first** point but the **second** one I am unable to.
Till now, I am storing all the items in a single table. Do I need to change the schema and split up the topics and articles in multiple tables to achieve both access patterns.

I need pagination at topic level and also at articles level.
Please suggest.

Comment: What's the schema for the primary key of your table? i.e what attributes are you using for partition and sort keys?

Comment: Topicid is the primary key @Tunmee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing table design, the only article pagination you can do is client side i.e. after you fetch a particular topic, you write some client-side code logic to skip x articles and get the slice you need.

**Why is this the only option?** By bundling all of a topic's articles inside the topic item, it's all or nothing, you can either get all the topic's articles or none. As of today, no DynamoDB API(Query, GetItem, etc.) will retrieve just a slice of the articles list attribute, they'll either return the entire attribute or not return it at all.

Client side pagination of course is a very wasteful approach as you'll have to fetch the entire article list and this might include lots of articles you're not interested in. A Dynamo item has a reasonable upper limit - [400kb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#limits-items) - so the size of the data might not be a big deal.

But do you have a restriction in place for the number of articles that can be on a topic? If no, then you have to think about that. A single Dynamo item can't exceed 400kb in size so the list of articles in a topic item mustn't grow in such a way that the topic item exceeds 400kb.

If your application is such that there shouldn't be a restriction to the number of articles on a topic then it would help if you considered re-modeling your table.

This is a suggested table structure that can achieve your desired access patterns in a more scalable way:

[image]

In the suggested table structure:

- Topics and articles are saved as separate items on the table, articles that belong to the same topic will share the same partition key i.e. `TOPIC<#TOPIC_ID>`, however, their sort key will differ.

With this approach, you can fetch and paginate articles in a topic with a query that looks like this:

```js
const getTopicArticles = async (topicId, lastArticleId = '', limit = 5) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: "<TableName>", // substitute with the right table name
    KeyConditionExpression: "PK = :pk AND #SK > :sk",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":pk": `TOPIC#${topicId}`,
      ":sk": `ARTICLE#${lastArticleId}`,
    },
    Limit: limit,
  };

  // make DYNAMO query api call
};
```

PS: The table structure above might look weird if you're not familiar with the DynamoDB single table design, you can check-out what single table design  is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-single-table-design-with-amazon-dynamodb/)

Comment: Hi @Tunmee 
Thanks for reply, it does makes sense but the sort key is including the meta about the topic also. Consider a topic has 20 articles, how to get them by pagination without the meta entry mixed up in that paginated results. And I wanted the articles to be paginated by the updatedTime. Please suggest

Comment: I need pagination on both topics and articles. Could you please suggest